# Lie Algebra, counterexample

Tags: lie-algebras

I am trying to find an example of an algebra over a field of characteristic p (prime) which satisfies anti-symmetry and Jacobi identity but is not a lie algebra. i.e., [x,x] is not zero.

Can one provide a pattern or a general method to modify existing Lie algebras in order to save anti-symmetry and Jacobi but **not** $[x,x]=0$ ?

Comment: Maybe in characteristic 2 try $[x,x]=y, [x,y]=0, [y,y]=0$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have $p=2$ otherwise antisymmetry implies the alternate identity $[x,x]=0$.

The minimal example taylored on the pattern below I can provide is the (multiplicative) subalgebra (over the field $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$) generated by
$$
E_{12}+E_{23}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}\ ;\ 
E_{13}=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
then, you can check you have your algebra.

Now, if, for some reason, you need to preserve some identities or relations of an existing Lie algebra (always in characteristic $2$ for the reason said before), proceed as follows

1. take you Lie algebra $(L,[-,-]_L)$ over $k$ (of characteristic $2$)

   add two dimensions by forming $L^{(1)}=L\oplus k.e_1\oplus k.e_2$

   extend the bracket $[x,y]$ to $L^{(1)}$ by

   1. $[x,y]_L$ if $x,y\in L$

      $[x,e_i]=[e_i,x]=0$ if $x\in L$

      $[e_1,e_1]=e_2;\ [e_2,e_i]=[e_i,e_2]=0$

then $L^{(1)}$ admits $L$ as a sector (direct summand and quotient), fulfills anti-symmetry and Jacobi, but not the alternate identity ($[x,x]=0$).